# Java. Сложить строки с помощю String.format

Tags: java, строки, printf

У меня задача выводить в консоль результаты некой операции, и я использовал такой подход:

`System.out.println(result + "text" + "eshoPeremennaia" + "text i tak dalee");`

Но мне на это дело был дан ответ: `нельзя складывать строки. используй String.format.`

Подскажите как это решается с помощю String.format я где не смотрю про этот метод везде рассказывают как знаки после запятой ограничить или как строку сдвинуть... 
Может кто знает как мне это вывести на консоль не складывая строки..?

Comment: `result` - это просто переменная? или в ней какой-то дополнительный текст?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Информацию по этой функции можно посмотреть в [справке](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Применительно к примеру из вопроса, вызов может выглядеть так:

```
System.out.println(
    String.format("%1$d text %2$d text i tak dalee", result, eshoPeremennaia)
);
```

[**пример на ideone**](http://ideone.com/oI4Ep2)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
вот такую ошибку выдает

Comment: @Павел, все зависит от типов переменных и их значений

Comment: @Павел, ну вы почитайте справку-то, на которую вам ссылку дали. Кто же знает, какого типа переменные вы в своем примере написали - вы же только отрывок привели. Для целых можно применять `%d`, для строк - `%s`, для вещественных куча своих форматов есть, для дат и времени - тоже, а `1$` `2$` вообще редко бывают нужны. Читайте, не ленитесь, в двух словах эту тему не описать. И по-русски полно материалов на эту тему.

Comment: @Павел, скорее всего нужно просто d заменить на s, если в переменных хранятся строки

Comment: А пардон, был не прав вы правы действительно у меня же тип другой. Спасибо!